# Which myth says that Eve wasn't the first wife of Adam, but Lilith?

Tags: mesopotamia, comparative, abrahamic-religions

According to the Hebrew Bible and Islamic tradition, Eve is known as Adam's wife.

However [some other works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_and_Eve#Adam_and_Eve_in_other_works) suggested something opposite.

Which myths suggest that Biblical Eve wasn't the first wife of Adam?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The story of Lilith being Adam's first wife can be found in the fifth question of the [Alphabet of ben Sirach](http://jewishchristianlit.com/Topics/Lilith/alphabet.html):

> "The angels who are in charge of medicine: Snvi, Snsvi, and Smnglof. After God created Adam, who was alone, He said, 'It is not good for man to be alone' (Gen. 2:18). He then created a woman for Adam, from the earth, as He had created Adam himself, and called her Lilith. Adam and Lilith began to fight. She said, 'I will not lie below,' and he said, 'I will not lie beneath you, but only on top. For you are fit only to be in the bottom position, while am to be in the superior one.' Lilith responded, 'We are equal to each other inasmuch as we were both created from the earth.' But they would not listen to one another. When Lilith saw this, she pronounced the Ineffable Name and flew away into the air. Adam stood in prayer before his Creator: 'Sovereign of the universe!' he said, 'the woman you gave me has run away.' At once, the Holy One, blessed be He, sent these three angels to bring her back.